# The rows continue to be different to each other

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

In each position of an $n \times n$ matrix there is a number. We know that all the rows of the matrix are different from each other. Show that we can delete a column so that the rows of the matrix that remain continue to be different to each other.

I have absolutely no attempt. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a well-known contest problem. Assume the contrary. Then, for every column $c$, there exist two rows -- say, the rows indexed $r_c$ and $s_c$ -- which differ only in column $c$. (Maybe there are several such pairs of rows, but pick out one at will.) Consider the graph on vertex set $\left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$, with an edge drawn connecting $r_c$ with $s_c$ for each $c$. This graph has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges (why?), thus contains a cycle. Show that the rows whose indices belong to this cycle must actually all be equal, contradicting the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Define an increasing sequence $s_0,...,s_n\in \{1,...,n\}$ as follows.

$s_0 = 1$ and $s_k$ is equal to the number of distinct rows in the $n\times k$ matrix consisting of the first $k$ columns of $M$.

It is evident that
this is an increasing sequence and if $s_{k-1} = s_k$, then we can delete the
$k$-th column without any rows becoming equal.

But $s_k \leq n$ for all $k$ and $s_0 = 1$ which implies that there must exist
a $k\in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $s_{k-1} = s_k$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Would it be better to start with s1 instead of $s_0$ (since $s_0$ has no meaning as such)? If all elements in the first column are equal, then we can delete that column. So we assume that there are at least two distinct elements in the first column and hence $s_1=2$